# Checking if signature field is signed using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I have a PDF file that I need to read with ITextSharp (version 5.1.1).  I need to iterate through the signature fields and verify whether the signature field has been signed or not.

I can already iterate through the signature fields, but I cannot figure out how to check if the signature field has been signed.  I do not want to verify the signature field as I am only interested in whether the field is signed or not, not its validity.

Can someone please point me in the right direction here?

Is there a property I can check for Siganturefields?

TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call [AcroFields.GetBlankSignatureNames()](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/AcroFields.html#getBlankSignatureNames%28%29).

With a [PdfReader](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html):

```
List<string> blanks = reader.AcroFields.GetBlankSignatureNames();
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks.  I was going down the route of parsing the PDF.  Can't believe I missed the GetBlankSignatureNames() method :)

Comment: I have an XFA form. For some reason whenever I write something to a form field that is not a signature field, it causes GetBlankSignatureNames() to return a empty list. More strangely, if I sign one of the signature fields with Acrobat Reader, then the function returns the list of empty signature names (less the one i signed.)